# Global variables inexplicably reset when adding form controls

Tags: vba, excel

I have a MS Excel spreadsheet that contains macros and that has worked flawlessly for years. I have copied and modified the spreadsheet innumerable times without issue. Until today. I made a copy of an existing, properly functioning file and ran into an inexplicable issue:

The spreadsheet includes a user-form that gathers certain data, some of which comes from option buttons contained within a frame. The data gathered is compared to global variables whose values are set in the workbook's Workbook_Open subroutine. For the existing workbook, I can beat on the form as hard as I want without issue. In the copy, I added an option button to the frame (that it - nothing else!) and upon clicking the form's 'submit' button, the values of the global variables are lost. (And this is without selecting the new option button.)

This behavior is repeatable and makes no sense. Can anyone suggest why Excel is behaving this strangely? Note - the file does not have any external references.

Update: This behavior happens when any new controls are added to the form...

Comment: Did you save and reopen? Variables stored in memory will be lost when the code recompiled when you added the button.

Comment: Would you happen to have an `End` instruction anywhere by any chance?

Comment: No End instruction

Answer (score 3):

Grasping at straws for lack of proper context, but here's a fix for the most likely scenario.

You likely have your globals assigned like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SomeGlobalVariable = 42
    AnotherGlobalVariable = "foo"
End Sub
```

Pull that out of the handler:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    AssignGlobalDefaults
End Sub
```

...and have this `AssignGlobalDefaults` procedure live in a standard module (.bas):

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module
Public SomeGlobalVariable As Long
Public AnotherGlobalVariable As String

Public Sub AssignGlobalDefaults()
    SomeGlobalVariable = 42
    AnotherGlobalVariable = "foo"
End Sub
```

Now when you make changes to the project that require recompiling the VBA code, go to the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) and type `AssignGlobalDefaults` before testing your code.

Save, then close. Now reopen. Still broken? Doubt so.

---

Global variables live in the *runtime context*. If the code is running, then they're alive. When you kill that context, global variables are still accessible, but since `Workbook_Open` is the only thing that assigns them (right?) and that handler only ever runs *when the workbook is being opened*, then the values aren't going to be automagically re-assigned.

The `End` keyword kills the execution context - if that keyword is anywhere in your code, remove it. Typing `End` in the *immediate pane* will do the same.

Changing project references also kills the execution context. Removing a module from the project does the same.

In other words, you can never assume that you can make changes to the VBA project and preserve global variable values. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, depending on what you've changed and how it affects the underlying P-Code.

The solution is to have a procedure responsible for initializing your globals, and to invoke it when you need your globals to be initialized.

Comment: All - thanks for the feedback and allowing me to clarify. The form on the existing spreadsheet works regardless of how many times it is opened/closed. When I add any control to the form, and then manually execute the Workbook_Open subroutine (in order to define the global variables), the form works properly the first time is it opened, but fails to work properly thereafter. The global variables are the symptom of the problem, not the cause.

Comment: @GRoston so... does that mean it's fixed or not?

Comment: FWIW If you're not going to show us any code, that's likely the only possible answer you can get.

Comment: Not fixed. I will 'answer my own question' in order to provide a link to the code and specific instructions to show the issue.

Comment: Problem (?) solved?? If I save and exit Excel, then re-open the file, the weird behavior goes away. Per the above comments, it is almost as if the execution context is stopped each time the form is closed during the session in which it was edited. Not sure what to say/think - I have done lots of Excel macro work and do not recall ever having experienced this oddness. Should I mark someone's response as being the answer?

Comment: @GRoston again, it's pretty hard to tell what's going on without seeing that form's code.